# Toshiba hard drive Compatibility

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive

Is the Toshiba 2TB 7200RPM SATA III hard drive model DT01ACA200 compatible with Ubuntu Linux version 14.04?  If not, I do not want to buy it.

Comment: what Toshiba model are you talking about ?

Comment: @RonaldAndrade: The model is "DT01ACA200"

Answer (score 0):

To find out if any hardware is certified for running under Ubuntu head to the [Official Ubuntu Certification catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/) and choose your hardware from there...

Furthermore, specific hardware recommendations are off-topic on this site...  :-(